# Adding info over graph obtained properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was able to run the "mpl_finance" candlestick_ohlc function and the graph appeared as expected, using the following (only relevant) code:

---

```
mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
                         quotes['open'], quotes['high'],
                         quotes['low'], quotes['close']),
                 width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.title('PETR4 daily quotes')
plt.show()
```

---

Now I would like to "add" on this graph (say) a horizontal red line at y = 26.5 ... how should I proceed?

(My real question is: how/where should I type something like axvline(...) so that I am able to make new data appear inside the same graph?)

Thanks!

Comment: `ax.axhline(y=26.5)` after `candlestick_ohlc`?

Comment: Hi, DavidG. It worked, as expected. Thanks.
I have tried ax.plt(ax, quotes['high'][i] for i in range(len(quotes.index)) that is what I really have in mind, but this does not work... should I open another post or  could you help me a bit more?

Comment: I could do it:  something like
maxvalues = ax.plot(quotes.index, quotes['high'], color='blue', lw=2)
works (right after candlestick_ohlc) ... cheers and thanks again!

Comment: If I need to "close" this request, or if I have the opportunity to upvote or give any kind of "reward" to DavidG, please (someone) help me to do so. Thanks!

Comment: You can answer the question yourself so that this question can help future readers?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, DavidG. Thanks again for your help. Hope to see you in other posts.

The interested readers will be able to adapt this "real stuff" below (it´s working)!

```
mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

fig, aux = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
aux.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
aux.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
aux.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

candlestick_ohlc(aux, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
                         quotes['open'], quotes['high'],
                         quotes['low'], quotes['close']),
                 width=0.6)

for i in range(len(features_period.date)):
    plt.plot(quotes.index, quotes.close , 'd', color='blue')

aux.xaxis_date()
aux.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.title('USIM5 daily quotes')

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]

display(candlestick_ohlc);
```

(The blue dots were added to the graph created by the module used/mentioned.)

Regards,
fskilnik